# Use long-polling to send data to Cloud from user PC

Tags: java, long-polling

I've got in the cloud a `UI` with a `JS` library. When `my_js_library.getDataFromUserPC(sql)` is called, it sends a `SQL` request to the user PC that will be executed over there.

Thing is I don't know the `IP` address of the user PC. One way to get it would be to use **long-polling**, through a third-party application.

**CLOUD**

`UI` => `JS` library => Third-party application

**User PC**

`Java` binary

The idea would be to use long-polling to regularly send the IP address of the user PC to the cloud application so that the JS library knows where and to whom send the SQL request:

Java binary to third-party application

Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What exactly is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: The goal would be to process the SQL request outside of the cloud, in the user PC. Using a JS API, it would send the request to the user through AJAX (or something else). But of course it needs to know the IP address.

Comment: thought about using something like mqtt or xmpp for that ? Both approaches would enable your UI to listen for commands.